# Cloudwatch logs "The remote name could not be resolved: 'logs.eu-west.amazonaws.com' when logging via NLog

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlog, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I had the thought of creating a custom Nlog target to send logs to CloudWatch Logs, seems straightforward enough but when I run my tests locally I get the following error - "WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'logs.eu-west.amazonaws.com'"

Can I send logs to CloudWatch Logs from applications running outside EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured your CloudWatch endpoint incorrectly. It should be: `logs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

[Amazon CloudWatch Regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cw_region)

Comment: Good spot in terms of the region name! On the 2nd point - it seems I can send logs from anywhere using the SDK.